# Type Casting between unrelated classes in JAVA

Tags: java, casting

Let there be two classes defined as follows:

```
Class A{
    int a;
}

Class B{
    int b;
}
```

A and B are two unrelated classes. Is there anyway I can cast an object of A to B? If yes, please explain the various options I have.

Comment: You could cast an instance of B to B but... The real question is, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: No. Only if they exist in the same type hierarchy or when you use a third class/interface to cast them both to.

Comment: How about reading this - [Object Oriented Programming Basics](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
Object b = new B();
A a = (A) b;
```

But this will throw a ClassCastException at runtime.

Instead you can use a copy Constructor

```
class B {
    public B(A a) { ... }

    public static B toB(A a) { return new B(a); }
}
```

And then you can do

```
B b = new B(a);
```

or

```
B b = toB(a);
```

Comment: Compiler would be smarter than that. There's no way for `A` and `B` to be in same hierarchy. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In C++ you can have a cast call a copy constructor. In Java you have to do this explicitly but you can perform the same basic operation which is to create an new object of the type you are "casting" to from the object you are casting.

Comment: I'm referring to the first part of your question. `A a = (A) new B();` will not compile with their example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for for the correction. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an upcast to a common super type, followed by a downcast

```
    (Dog)(Pet)aCat
```

Of course, `Object` is the supertype of any type, so we can use it to cast between any 2 types

```
    (Apple)(Object)aCat
```

Usually, this makes no sense, and it will cause runtime exception. But it may be helpful in some generic cases. For example, `Supplier<Integer>` and `Supplier<number>` are "unrelated"; as a matter of fact, they are mutually exclusive, i.e. the intersection is empty, or, no object can belong to the two types at the same time. Nevertheless, we may want to cast `Supplier<Integer>` to `Supplier<Number>`, due to lack of variance in Java, combined with the existence of erasure. See this [case study](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Casting_Between_Concrete_Types).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would break a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

Though JAVA allows you to type cast object across unrelated classes i.e. which are not in class hierarchy. This is allowed because of the below case

```
String s = (String)list.get(1);
```

Well list can certainly contain different type of object and while calling such a method it could return String as well.

Coming to your question you will succeed in typecasting but at runtime you will get `ClassCastException` .

You can type cast object B to type A iff `B IS-A A` that means B is a subtype of A. If both are not in a hierarchy then type casting them does not make sense. just like you can not type cast an `Animal` type to `Furniture` type.